# Manipulating nested numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])
```

I want to divide elementwise by 10 and then round elementwise (<0.5 rounding down to 0).

Comment: Just do it? `np.round(array / 10)` This will be subject to a slightly different rounding bahaviour than you specified (depending on the python version) but this will only affect `.5` values

Comment: This produces the error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'.

Comment: yes, I used numpy.asarray. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
                  [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                  [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]], dtype=float)
result = np.round(array / 10)
```

`result` will be `array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                     [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
                     [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])`

Answer (score 0):

There is a rounding function in `numpy` that can take care of rounding: [`numpy.round()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
                  [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                  [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])

np.round(array / 10)

# array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
#        [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

this will however round `x.5` (if `x` is even) down but `y.5` (if `y` is odd) up. See the notes in [`np.around()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around)